# conversion of decimal formatted date into date in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime, sql-server-2012

I want to convert the decimal format date into normal date format in sql.
Below is the example - 
I am having the date in decimal format like  '1512137620000' , I want to convert it into normal standard format MM/DD/YYYY.
Many thanks for your help.

Comment: what is ur required o/p for above decimal value i.e `1512137620000`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what your base date is, and what your decimal number represents (milliseconds, seconds), you can do it like this:

```
SELECT DATEADD(MILLISECOND, 1512137620000, '19000101')
```

With your given decimal number, this statement will produce an arithmetic overflow (the second parameter for DATEADD is an integer); I would divide the decimal number by 1.000 and try

```
SELECT DATEADD(SECOND, 1512137620, '19000101')
```

This results in 1947-12-02 14:13:40.000  so I suspect your base date is maybe 19700101, then the result would be 2017-12-01 14:13:40.000.

Then for converting into MM/DD/YYYY:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), DATEADD(SECOND, 1512137620, '19700101'), 103)
```

Comment: 1,512,137,620,000 is too large for dateadd(millisecond